# Is there a way to adjust space between subplots when layout='constrained'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to remove the vertical space between two specific axes; however `plt.figure(layout='constrained')` prevents `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)`.

### With `layout='constrained'`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8),layout='constrained')
# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 1)
axsUp = subfigs[0].subplots(1, 3)
subfigsnest = subfigs[1].subfigures(1, 2, width_ratios=[1, 2])
ax = subfigsnest[0].subplots(1)
axsnest = subfigsnest[1].subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
subfigsnest[1].subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

- Generally subplots are in place; but there is a gap between ax5 & ax6

[image: Generally subplots are in place; but there is a gap between ax5 & ax6]

### Without `layout='constrained'`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8),layout='constrained')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 1)
axsUp = subfigs[0].subplots(1, 3)
subfigsnest = subfigs[1].subfigures(1, 2, width_ratios=[1, 2])
ax = subfigsnest[0].subplots(1)
axsnest = subfigsnest[1].subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
subfigsnest[1].subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

- Desired ax5 & ax6

[image: Desired ax5 & ax6]

Using `subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` with `layout='constrained'` doesn't work and it produces the warning **UserWarning: This figure was using a layout engine that is incompatible with subplots_adjust and/or tight_layout; not calling subplots_adjust.**.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `layout='constrained'`, try setting up the plots using a [nested `GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_nested.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-gridspec-nested-py), setting `hspace=0` only for the second row. This ensures that all axes are aligned neatly, while still allowing `ax5` and `ax6` to be glued together sharing a common x-axis.

For example, this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
gs0 = GridSpec(2, 1, figure=fig)  # set up two rows

gs1 = gs0[0].subgridspec(1, 3)    # set up 1st row such that it has 3 columns
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 0])  # create ax1
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 1])  # create ax2
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 2])  # create ax3

gs2 = gs0[1].subgridspec(2, 3, hspace=0)       # set up second row such that it has 2 sub-rows and 3 sub-columns
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:, 0])               # create ax4 such that it spans all sub-rows but only 1 sub-column
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[0, 1:])              # create ax5 in the 1st sub-row but spanning the last 2 sub-columns 
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[1, 1:], sharex=ax5)  # create ax6 in the 2nd sub-row but spanning the last 2 sub-columns
ax5.tick_params(labelbottom=False)             # remove ax5 x-axis ticks
ax5.set_yticks(ax5.get_yticks()[1:])           # make sure 1st ax5 ticklabel does not overlab with last ax6 ticklabel
ax6.set_yticks(ax6.get_yticks()[:-1])          # make sure last ax6 ticklabel does not overlab with 1st ax5 ticklabel

for i, ax in enumerate([ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]):
    ax.text(0.5, 0.5, f"ax{i+1}", transform=ax.transAxes, ha='center', va='center', fontsize='xx-large')
```

produces:

[image: spacing with nested gridspec]

Comment: It seems pretty clear that using `layout='constrained'` is not actually a requirement for the question; the goal is simply to get the desired layout - with the plots properly justified while also avoiding vertical space between the last two plots. From what I can tell, this approach works exactly as intended, so I edited the prose to be a bit shorter, clearer and more confident.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, Fair enough, but should the question title be adjusted in that case, too?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't have a good idea for that at the moment.